# Statement Execution order in SQL Server SQL Script

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I am having trouble with a sql script that seems to be related to the execution order of the statements or possibly just error checking that sql server does prior to starting.

This is a simplification of the code but for background, the table finalTable is cleared and repopulated by this script.  It already exists in the DB but does not have new columns that are being added.  For reference in the example, pretend Col1 is an existing column and Col2 is new.

**If I run the code all together, I get a message saying Invalid Column name 'Col2'.  If I run each block individually, everything works fine.**

Block A:

```
SQL to create temporary tables
```

Block B:

```
drop table dbo.finalTable;
create table dbo.finalTable (col1 int, col2 int);
```

Block C:

```
insert into dbo.finalTable(col1, col2) select col1, col2 from #tempTable;
```

Comment: As an additional note - after receiving the invalid column name message, if I query finalTable, it does not have the new column and still has the old data.  If I query the tempTable in that session, it has the correct, current data.

Comment: Show your entire script.

Comment: I'd love to but it's 1800 lines and contains proprietary information.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself

Comment: The best thing to do in your case is create a small script that reproduces your issue and post it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The script snippets you posted are not detailed enough to pinpoint the exact cause of the error but the symptoms suggest [deferred name resolution](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190686(v=sql.105).aspx). The issue is not statement execution order but compilation order.

SQL Server checks for syntax errors when a batch of statements is submitted for execution. If syntactically correct, statements referencing existing objects are validated against existing schema.  Compilation of statements referencing non-existing objects are deferred until execution time. Deferred name resolution allows one to create a table and use it in the same batch:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.finalTable (col1 int);
--Compilation of this statement is not done until execution time due to deferred name resolution
SELECT col1 FROM dbo.finaltable;
GO
```

Compilation of the entire batch will fail when a statement references a non-existing column of an existing table. No statements, including the first `SELECT` `ALTER TABLE`, are executed in this batch because col2 does not exist when the batch is compiled:

```
SELECT col1 FROM dbo.finaltable;
ALTER TABLE dbo.finaltable 
    ADD col2 int NULL;
SELECT col1, col2 FROM dbo.finaltable;
GO
```

Answer (score 0):

Is it the same database the script execution and finalTable exists when you executed the script as whole? You may try to

```
 IF OBJECT_ID('databasename.dbo.finalTable', 'U') IS NOT NULL 
      DROP TABLE databasename.dbo.finalTable;
```